# Improving Mongoose Populate Perfomance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Consider the following Document

```
{ 
  lists: {
    list1: [ ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2) ],
    list2: [ ObjectId(1), ObjectId(3) ],
    list3: [ ObjectId(4), ObjectId(5), ObjectId(1)]
  }
}
```

it contains array of references to another collections say `Products` I want names of all those products when I return the response of the API. So I used populate

```
Something.populate({ path:'lists', select: 'name')
```

This is working fine and it fills the list arrays with the name of products. But I can see in mongoose debug mode that each of those queries are executed separately.

```
Product.find({ _id: { $in:[ 1, 2 ]})
Product.find({ _id: { $in:[ 1, 3 ]}) 
Product.find({ _id: { $in:[ 4, 5, 1 ]})
```

These list can have huge number of elements with common ids across lists which means mongoose internally queries same id multiple times.

I am also using cachegoose but as these are populate queries the cache values doesn't have any effect in these queries. Any suggestion to improve this performance.

Comment: if you are using mongodb and mongoose then why wouldn't using aggregation for query optimization and performation.

Comment: @AshokPatidar This is just retrieval of data and populate sub documents There is no aggregation happening in this query.